# Xml Parsing using state machines

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, state-machine

Is it a good practise to implement xml parsing in a state machine? If yes what are the major states we have to handle?

Comment: What do you mean under "parsing"? Writing your own parser?

Comment: Parsing with a state machine usually means regular grammer parsing. XML uses more complicated level of grammer so it seems impossible. I think we need a REAL parser generator to build fully functional DOM parser.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong ,state machine implementation of the same cant be done using DOM method.

Comment: No. XML requires a push-down automata to be parsed, because it has matching parentheses; an FSA can't match them if they are nested arbitrarily deeply.   But that isn't your real problem: XML is a messy language if you handle all the details; in this, you are by far better off to get a library where somebody has done all this work.  If all you want is "sloppy XML" with nested tags and raw text without all the extra bells and whistles (this works for lots of applications), you can write a simple recursive descent parser to do this quite easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're writing your own parser "from scratch" - then you should probably make such kind of a sandwich:

- plain text string
- SAX-type callbacks
- Code, that builds DOM, based on previous level

So level 1 can (and should) be done in an FSM, I would do it with a set of states like Initial, InTagName, InAttrName, InAttrValue, InCDATA, etc. There won't be too many, just a couple page switch statement.

Still, there's still plenty of work in case you need correct schema/namespace/xpath/etc support.

So why not just take an existing solution?